# Confusion matrix for sklearn tree with categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have trained a sklearn tree with default parameters on a dataset in which all data are categorical. The dataset is about cars.

[image: An example of dataset]

The rightmost column is the label associated with the attributes. Each row is an input instance. Because sklearn cannot handle categorical data, I used a dictionary to map each possible input for a feature into a dictionary and mapped them to positive integers so the dataset is no longer categorical and now consists of only integers where each has a meaning for each feature. I used the new training set to train the classifier.

```
#x_train= training dat
#y_train= training data label
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I'm able to calculate accuracy for an arbitrary `x_test` and `y_test` input with `score(x_test, y_test)`. The question is how can I draw and visualize the confusion matrix for `x_test` and `y_test` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plot_confusion_matrix` to visually represent a confusion matrix. You only need to pass the fitted estimator (`clf` in your case) along with the input (`X_test`) and the true target values (`y_test`). Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test)
plt.show()
```

The plot can further be customized e.g. by providing labels other than the ones in `y_test`. For more information, have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn-metrics-plot-confusion-matrix).